# Типизированная распаковка объекта

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, сопоставление-с-образцом

Как в таком коде на TypeScript'е указать, что параметр `text` должен иметь тип `string`?

```
function test({ text: text }) {
    console.log(text);
}

test({ text: "Some text" });
```

Компилируется он верно в

```
function test(_a) {
    var text = _a.text;
    console.log(text);
}
test({ text: "Some text" });
```

Но указать тип переменной у меня не получается.
Конструкция `{ text: text : string }` некорректна.
Конструкция `{ text: string }` работает согласно спецификации ES6 - поле `text` превращается в переменную `string`, имеющую в тайпскрипте тип `any` .

Экспериментировал тут: http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что в тайпскрипте можно указать тип свойств анонимных объектов и/или при инициализации свойств.

Comment: @Etki, но ведь он съел такое объявление.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16179661/2908793

Comment: @Etki, я сам догадался благодаря твоему комментарию))))

Comment: @Etki, слишком старая ссылка - не уверен, что распаковка тогда уже была. UPDATE: Хотя я несколько неправ, там по сути очень похожая штука.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Неожиданно осенило - типизировать надо не поле аргумента, а сам аргумент:

```
function test({ text } : { text: string }) {
    console.log(text);
}
```